# Android SlidingMenu Play Store style

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using [this sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/pull/700). I got blocked and cant detect where i can configure to show as Play Store style. Is it possible here ?

```
private void setSlidingMenu() {
    slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    slidingMenu.setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
}
```

Comment: leave this lib try to build with material design lib.... http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: working but how to reach that menu icon from tooblar ?